# How to edit a calendar input element in capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, webdriver, capybara

I'm currently trying to edit a calendar input element and set a new date. Here is what I'm trying to do.

Element:

```
<input class="ant-calendar-input " placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" value="03/01/2022">
```

Xpath:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/input
```

My code:

```
find("ant-calendar-input").set(value='01/01/2022')
```

I'm getting an error that capybara is unable to find this element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"ant-calendar-input" as a CSS selector would look for an element of type 'ant-calendar-input' whereas the element you show is of type 'input' with a class of 'ant-calendar-input'. A valid CSS selector to match that element would be something like

```
find('input.ant-calendar-input').set('01/01/2022')
```

That being said, you claim this is a calendar input, but the input element is just a text input. I assume this means you are using some type of JS widget that is bound to the `input` element and therefore may have hidden the original input. If that's the case then you'll need to interact with the elements generated by the widget (like a user would have to) rather than directly with the input element